# Symfony Route Not found "GET /articles/"

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'm following this tutorial:

https://openclassrooms.com/courses/construisez-une-api-rest-avec-symfony/introduction-a-la-serialisation-avec-jmsserializer

I did what the teacher want me to do, but when I try to access  *http://api/app_dev.php/articles*
I get the following error:

> No route found for "GET /articles/"

[debug router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Sm0y.png)

[function in error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX4Dw.png)

Mycontroller [the controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcNfN.png)

Comment: So you allow only `POST` and expect `GET` to work?

Comment: As said since it's a `POST` request you should trying to access your action through a software like Postman for example :)

Comment: yes i do, i use Postman, it return me the same error Grrrr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `debug:routes` it shows that the route /articles is `POST` and not `GET`, change the method from POST to GET please inside your controller or inside your routing file

Comment: i did, it is in the top of the msg. i didn't configure any routing file, it use annotation

Comment: i delete the S at articles: @Route("/article", name="article_create") and next try has works... i put back the S at articles: @Route("/articles", name="article_create"), and it's working fine. Thank you alessandro for your help !

Comment: Glad to help you! @gorgorbhey

Answer (score 0):

The route you try is /articles/

But the route defined is /articles